# Using Ruby on Rails with Knockoutjs Helper Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, knockout.js, helper

I have the following code:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: people" width=700px>
    <tr class ="people">
      <td data-bind="text: $data.person.last_name"><%# person.full_name %></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.person.account_id"></td>
      <td><%# link_to "show", person %></td>
      <td><%# link_to "edit", edit_person_path(person) %></td>
      <td><%# link_to "[x]", person, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
      <td><button data-bind="click: $parent.removePlace">Info</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and I'm not sure how to use Ruby's link_to helper method with knockoutjs bound objects. How do you use Ruby helper methods with knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to mix server side ruby code with javascript, in your example, all the ruby code you injected is being replaced by knockout once it runs the `foreach:` binding.

If you have access to the "people" array on the server, you probably should be using ruby to iterate through the elements. If you're willing to stick with rendering on the client side, I guess the proper way would be to craft the links using `<a data-bind="attr: { href: 'link here' }">`